# Sencha Architect 4.3.2 is giving framework error: cannot read property 'add' of undefined

Tags: sencha-architect

I upgraded from Sencha architect 4.2 beta to official 4.3.2 release by following these instructions [How to upgrade Sencha Architect to 4.3.2](https://www.sencha.com/blog/upgrading-7-x-sencha-architect-app-to-ext-js-7-6/).  Now when I open my Modern projects I am getting the error 'Design view: framework error: cannot read property 'add' of undefined' in the log panel and the deign view of the panel is blank.  Code shows OK.  My Classic app opens and shows the design view just fine.  Unfortunately our subscription has lapsed so I cannot raise a case with Sencha.  Does anyone have any suggestions?  What additional info can I provide?

Cmd and framework are both 7.6.

Its weird - once the app is open in the Architect one can eventually get it to display the design view by viewing code and then viewing design tab again.  It might take several attempts at alternating between code and design and clicking on different parts of a panel.  Once it displays properly it will continue to display OK till you close and open the architect again, and then you have to start all over with the clicking around.

Answer (score 0):

Note I'm using **ExtJS 7.3 modern**

The *cannot read property 'add' of undefined'* is usualy an **id** issue. Make sure every component has an id set for it on the config panel.
Though this error doesn't affect the overall stability of the app, you can save and build the application like normally.

Now for the clicking between *code* & *design*, there's not a solution I have found. It's an annoying bug for sure, but it's not a big deal.

Comment: I have specifically avoided giving objects an id as many of my panels are designed to have multiple instance open at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

It could also be due to using the Data UI Builder as it creates add: function's and that conflicts with an internal overridden add function.

I've also found that is has no bearing on the whether the project works or not.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion however we have not used the Data UI Builder.

Comment: Hey David, yeah there seems to be a minor bug in the IDE, as what you explain is the exact way SA opens for me.  It takes several minutes for my project to load the design pane. I also see the same error message in the log.  But as far as I can tell it doesn't effect my program at all, just a nuisance.  And just to compare, my server is an unlocked  i9-10900K running at around 4.113 gHz, so its definitely something to do with the IDE being slow to load up.  Anyway good luck, and if you like, we can start an email correspondence to exchange ideas and/or help each other . Take care.

Comment: Hi @pjackson,  I'd be happy to exchange emails.  How do we do that via stack exchange?

Comment: @David, so it looks like I can only invite people via email, if you'd like post your email and I'll send the invite, I just created sencha-idea-exchange.  My public email is jwareservices@gmail.com, feel free to send your email to that one?

Comment: Oops, I wrote that before this.  I just created a team call sencha-idea-exchange.  I thought that we could use it as a place to communicate.